# Spring Mvc/Jpa-OneToMany : How to display a list of class associated to another one

Tags: jpa, spring-mvc, one-to-many

I've got a class Module with a OneToMany binding with a class Sequence.
My aim is to show the list of Modules, and by clicking on one of them, display the associated list of Sequences 
But it doesn't work, I have a HTTP 500 error.

Here there is my controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="formation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView allModules() {
List<Module> allModules = moduleService.findAll();
return new ModelAndView("formation", "modules", allModules);
}

@RequestMapping(value="sequences/{module}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String displaySequences(@PathVariable ("module") Module module, Model model) {
List<Sequence> allSequences = sequenceService.findByModule(module);
model.addAttribute("sequences", allSequences);
return "sequences";
}
```

and the jsp which show the list of modules to return the list of sequences

```
<c:forEach items="${modules}" var="module">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="sequences/${module}">${module.titre}</a>
                    <br/>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </c:forEach>
```

So, where does my error come from?

It works when I do that:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/sequences/{moduleId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String displaySequences(@PathVariable ("moduleId") Long moduleId, Model model) {
Module module = moduleService.findById(moduleId);
model.addAttribute("module", module);
return "sequences";
}
```

and I change the link with :

```
<a href="sequences/${module}">${module.titre}
```

but I'd like to understand my error.

Comment: Did you see what is being rendered by JSP in place of ${module}?

Comment: it's a kind of code /myAppli/sequences/com.almerys.jpa.tomcatspring.Module@12b0f0ae where com.almerys.jpa.tomcatspring is the package where the module class is located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you weren't able to display sequences is Spring doesn't know how to parse this

`/cmap-web/sequences/com.almerys.jpa.tomcatspring.Module@12b0f0ae`

into Module instance.

You can read on this in Spring docs [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates) in the section's `16.3.2.2 URI Template Patterns` last paragraph. I paste it here for convenience.

> A @PathVariable argument can be of any simple type such as int, long, Date, etc. Spring automatically converts to the appropriate type or throws a TypeMismatchException if it fails to do so. You can also register support for parsing additional data types. See Section 16.3.3.14, “Method Parameters And Type Conversion” and Section 16.3.3.15, “Customizing WebDataBinder initialization”.

Comment: I probably didn't everything well since I wanted to convert Module class to String by adding

    `@InitBinder
     public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
      binder.registerCustomEditor(Module.class, new PropertiesEditor());
     }`

into my controller after reading the Spring doc in section 16.3.2.2 URI Template Patterns and [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion), but now I have a HTTP 400 error.
What's wrong ?

Comment: I tried a mix of [this](http://empire5.com/development/binding-a-custom-object-in-spring-3/) and [this](http://empire5.com/2011/05/) but I had a white page

Comment: I thought it was a default method, so I just wrote that. Afterwards, I changed PropertiesEditor by ModuleEditor whose code is

            `public class ModuleEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport { 
    private final Module module; 
    /****constructor***
    @Override 
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
           setValue(module); 
         } 
    }`
But I think the problem came from Spring Data Jpa. I use this and I don't know what is expected as custumer value (module value in my case).

If you think about a simplier solution, I'd appreciate.

Comment: I suggest using [this](http://empire5.com/development/binding-a-custom-object-in-spring-3/)  solution. The one you posted previously.

Comment: it still doesn't work. I think the problem came from the line `countryService.get(Long.parseLong(text))` since I can't define a method get in ModuleService that return a module in fonction of a number which is not its Id. I tried evrything but everything failed, so I think I'ff do differently

Comment: Why can't you just inject ModuleRepository into ModuleEditor and call it as follows: moduleRepository.findOne(Long.parseLong(text)) ?